# THREE.js - Is there a way for easy building of a subset of three.js features?

Tags: three.js

Current version of three.js, even minified is about half a megabyte heavy beast. Is there a way (other than hacking the sources) to build only a needed subset of features in order to keep the HTTP served file as small as possible?

Comment: Have you considered accepting the answer?

Comment: Yes, I shall accept the answer but am usually holding my horses for some good time before doing that.

Comment: have you considered accepting the answer? @silverdr

Comment: [tag:three.js] has a very low acceptance rate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357466/the-three-js-tag-has-really-bad-questions

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually not 100% sure on the terminology nor what exactly does the magic, but with a babel/webpack build system, i can pick the modules i want and export them like this

```
//myThree.js
export { LineBasicMaterial } from 'three/src/materials/LineBasicMaterial'
export { MultiMaterial } from 'three/src/materials/MultiMaterial'
export { Mesh } from 'three/src/objects/Mesh'
export { Object3D } from 'three/src/core/Object3D'
...
```

Then you should be able to say

```
//myFoo.js

import * as THREE from './myThree'
```

You can also import directly from `three/src`, module by module, but i found this to be very tedious if done manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there's no super easy way. There's no checklist utility or anything at least. But the biggest issue is that individual components are really small, and are interdependent on more general functions. I.E. you could delete a file like THREE.PlaneGeometry if you don't need it, but that file itself is really small:

```
function PlaneGeometry( width, height, widthSegments, heightSegments ) {

        Geometry.call( this );

        this.type = 'PlaneGeometry';

        this.parameters = {
            width: width,
            height: height,
            widthSegments: widthSegments,
            heightSegments: heightSegments
        };

        this.fromBufferGeometry( new PlaneBufferGeometry( width, height, widthSegments, heightSegments ) );

    }
```

Because it takes advantage of PlaneBufferGeometry, so you're not really saving any real space by deleting it, so then you have to delete planebuffergeometry as well to start seeing any benefit, and even then, most of planebuffergeometry makes use of the attributes of bufferGeometry, which I'm guessing you can't delete unless you don't want to use any meshes.

But it can create weird side effects. Doing a quick search of the source, I see that planebuffergeometry gets used if you want to have a texture as background to your renderer. It creates a piece of geometry with no depth or fog test and applies your background texture as a map to that planebuffergeometry.

Even if you don't plan to use that feature, it still might throw a nullpointerexception on the call of the render function because it relies on planebuffergeometry.

It's hard to predict the interaction of components, so it's hard to say definitively what is essential to you and what is not, and it's hard to identify specific sections that are a) not essential and b) are large in size.

Probably the best you could do is run the build yourself, modifying the includes. Building a repo yourself is a different issue than your question that I don't know how to do, but for which there are likely tutorials. [but I found a pretty concise set of src's](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/Three.js) which I think is part of the build process for the Threejs repo. you could try stripping out components, building, and then seeing what still works.